# how to use a sent variable from php into vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am already sending a variable from laravel to my vuejs like below : but when i want to use it in a component as an string it gives not defined error my vue component code is like below

```
 export default {
        props: ['reserve_end'],
        data(){
            return {
                date: '',


            }
        },
}
// the component part
 import VuePersianDatetimePicker from 'vue-persian-datetime-picker'
    Vue.use(VuePersianDatetimePicker, {
        name: 'custom-date-picker',
        props:
            {
                min: //i want to use the reserve_end here as an string


            }
    });
```

and finally the html markup

```
                    <custom-date-picker v-model="date"></custom-date-picker>
```

but in the end it wont load and gives error that reserve_end is not defined i want to know how can i pass this reserve_end to the datepicker as an string
here is the devtoll picture of tracing 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you got the passing right? Tried with Vue devtools inspection?

Comment: Yes i even print it but i cant access it from the above so i get the error

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović check the edited answer i atached picture of devtoll

Comment: In that case, just pass the prop to the component: `<custom-date-picker :min="date"></custom-date-picker>`, with second binding, or just directly like `:min="reserve_end"`.

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović can i convert it to string there ?? because now i get no error of not found any more but the time picker not working i saw on documentaion that it only recives string and i gues my value my not be string

Comment: Well, anytime, you passing something you can do like, `variable.toString();`.

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović again not working even after converting to string a bit wierd , can :min="..." and min=".." be different ??

Comment: So, i I get it, you are passing value from Laravel to one component, and then to date-picker, right? :)

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović yes yes benji thats what i am looking for :)

Comment: can i pass and accep it directly in datepicker component ??

Comment: Yes, of course, just import the creator's component, in your `app.js`, as you have imported your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190793/discussion-between-farshad-and-benjamin-beganovic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`// First component (getting value from Laravel):
export default {
  props: ['reserve_end']
}`

Now, in the first component, you should have an access to `this.reserve_end`.

`// template of first component
<template>
  <second-component :date="reserve_end"></second-component>
</template>`

Let's pass the value to another component, using same technique - props.

`// Second component (getting value from first component
export default {
  props: ['date']
}`

Now, in the second, component we can:

`{{ date }}`, to get the date :)

However, don't forget to inspect each component Vue devtools.

Comment: acctualy its one component and one plugin that i exported so i want to pass data from the export default to vue.use(datepicker) , my last question is how can i receive  the reserve_end in the props of downpart

Comment: 'plugin' is yet another component, ready-to-get embeded into any sistem. Just as you would pass data from your own components, same should work for the 'plugins'.